# How to make model for a full fledged blog in django ?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I followed a django tutorial and made a basic blog, but now I want to make a blog in which I can add multiple multimedia files like images, videos, may be sound clips, presentation, slide shows along with text.

But I am not able to design the schema for my models.

This is my current schema.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And is it possible for me to give django admin a new look or it is not advised to play with admin app.

Answer (score 0):

> "Don't reinvent the wheel."

To build an admin page that consist of what you list above: images, videos, may be sound clips, presentation, slide shows along with text, is a very time consuming project and it does take a lot deeper understanding of Django.

You can take a took at [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/). I believe it is, what you're looking for.

Comment: I want to understand the model schema and how to design models for different purposes, I might end up using Mezzanine, but I want to do this on my own.

Comment: I want to do this for experiment and get knowledge.